# Bluetooth Inputstream unwanted splitting

Tags: android, bluetooth, message, inputstream

i'm having troubles with bluetooth, my connection is established and i can send data to my module, but receiving always splits my bytearray, the messages from the module are separated in the first byte and the rest of the message, so instead of single message i'm getting two.
I used the bluetooth chat-example.

```
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(ActivityTrafficSignChooserUpperSign.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, bytes, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
                //Log.d(TAG, bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the part of my activity:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {


            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), readMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
         }}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you had any luck resolving this since you posted this? I'm considering making a read request 1 byte at a time.

Comment: Ohh sorry for the late response, it seems the bluetooth module (btm-222) was cousing the problems. i tried other chipsets and the worked all fine...